# Android app crashes for some users when applying transformation with Picasso

Tags: android, image, picasso

I have built an app where some users (admins) can log on to an admin account on my webpage and change some content, for example the background image in the app. As back end I'm using Parse.com, and the app loads its background image from there. I'm using Picasso to load background images in the app. In some Activities I want the background to blur, so I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/Sefford/5eeb2d88f15db78fe3e2) Blur Transformation and load the image with the following code:

```
int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(apiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            // Blur the image
            final BlurTransformation blurTransformation = new BlurTransformation(this, 20);
            // Load the background image with blur
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(backgroundPictureURL)
                    .transform(blurTransformation)
                    .into(backgroundView);
        } else {
            // Load the background image without blur
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(backgroundPictureURL)
                    .into(backgroundView);
        }
```

I have enabled crash reports with Parse, and I am now getting reports that the app is crashing for some users when trying to apply the Blur Transformation. This is the stack trace that I receive:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Transformation blurred crashed with exception.
com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter$3.run                                         BitmapHunter.java:434
android.os.Handler.handleCallback                                               Handler.java:739
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage                                              Handler.java:95
android.os.Looper.loop                                                          Looper.java:135
android.app.ActivityThread.main                                                 ActivityThread.java:5254
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke                                                 Native Method
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke                                                 Method.java:372
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run                      ZygoteInit.java:898
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main                                         ZygoteInit.java:693
Caused by: android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Bitmap has an unsupported format for this operation
android.renderscript.Allocation.validateBitmapFormat                            Allocation.java:537
android.renderscript.Allocation.copyTo                                          Allocation.java:1257
se.myapplication.main.CustomUI.BlurTransformation.transform                       BlurTransformation.java:60
com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.applyCustomTransformations                    BitmapHunter.java:429
com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt                                          BitmapHunter.java:238
com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run                                           BitmapHunter.java:159
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call                             Executors.java:422
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run                                             FutureTask.java:237
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker                               ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run                              ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587
java.lang.Thread.run                                                            Thread.java:818
com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run                                    Utils.java:411
```

The line of code in the Blur Transformation class that the stack trace is refering to is this line:

```
output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);
```

The image format is either jpg or png and when trying on my phone and on the emulator, there isn't a problem, so the crash only seem to occur for some users, and they seem to have Android 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 (like I do aswell, and there isn't a problem for me).

I'm getting nowhere with this, so any help is appreciated! What could be causing the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: if that's of any help, the code that throws that exception is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/rs/java/android/renderscript/Allocation.java

Comment: I would say that `BlurTransformation.transform` creates a bitmap that renderscript does not like. Can you post the code for that?

Comment: In particular, how do you create `blurredBitmap`

Comment: As I said, I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/Sefford/5eeb2d88f15db78fe3e2) library, so the blurredBitmap is created like it is in the library :)

Comment: when creating a new bitmap, android uses the origin's config. You can start by checking if the source's config is null or not, and may be either copy the config from the source using `setConfig`, or setting a default config altogether

Comment: So it could have something to with what's said in [this post](http://marcin-kozinski.github.io/dynamic-blurred-app-background.html) in Step 5 and 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in Step 5 and 6 in [this post](http://marcin-kozinski.github.io/dynamic-blurred-app-background.html) by Marcin Koziński!

Comment: If this solved your issue, please tag as accepted (check the v button, below the answer indentifier)

Comment: Can't until tomorrow, then I will!

Answer (score 0):

From your error log:

`Caused by: android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Bitmap has an unsupported format for this operation`

They are using Bitmap images. Even though usually you can check for metadata before applying an operation, most services dont, they just filter by the file name (like *.img, *.jpg, *.png).

I have been in a project where sometimes the file was produced in a way, then re-rendered as bmp, to increase their "quality". While the images were bmp encoded, they were kept as .jpg names. As far as I can tell, this seems common, specially on images taken from the internet (the mismatch between names and content)

Comment: How come it is almost always working with the jpg and png images then?